# MEAN application doesn't connect to the mongodb database when shutting down the net connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I do a test in MEAN stack application with express.js, monk and angularjs in localhost. But, I notice:

-Even with network closed and without angularjs framework, the application runs fine;

-When the net connection is running,the application runs well even with angularjs framework;

-But once I shut down the net connection and run the application, I get a blank page in my browser with this error in the console:

```
C:\Users\kossi\Desktop\blogapp\test3\node_modules\monk\node_modules\mongodb\lib\
mongodb\mongo_client.js:409
          throw err
          ^

Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kossi\Desktop\blogapp\test3\node_modules\monk\
node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:556:25)
    at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
    at emit (events.js:175:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kossi\Desktop\blogapp\test3\node_modules\monk\
node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kossi\Desktop\blogapp\test3\node_modules\mon
k\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at connectErrorNT (net.js:996:8)
```

What I actually understand is - someone can correct me if it's not true - my application failing to connect to mongodb database comes from angularjs framework, specifically the $resource service in the ngResource module. But I can't figure out why  this, since I don't use any CDN content.

Can someone help with deep understanding?

Comment: it looks for me that you are stopping car engine and wondering why it is not driving? - try to stop an interface instead of full network

Comment: What are you expecting to happen if no *mongod* instance is running?